# React Router dom returning empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react router dom v6. If I write routes like this:

```
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/posts' element={<Posts/>}/>
            <Route path='/posts/:id' element={<PostDetails/>}/>
            <Route path='/about' element={<About/>}/>
            <Route path='/' element={<Main/>}/>
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
```

it's okay, useParams returning { id: number } in the PostDetails component.

However If I write routes like the following:

```
            <Routes>
                {routes.map(({path, component}) =>
                    <Route path={path} element={component()}/>
                )}
            </Routes>
```

useParams returns empty object. Why this happening?

PS: `routes` is an array of objects containing path & component values. The actual `routes` value is:

```
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Main,
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        component: About,
    },
    {
        path: '/posts',
        component: Posts,
    },
    {
        path: '/posts/:id',
        component: PostDetails,
    },
]
```

Comment: How about if you use `{routes.map(({path, component:Component}) => <Route path={path} element={<Component />}/>)}`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I'm not sure if I understand what you meaning. What's this `Component` type?
However, it seems like I understand now what's wrong. I tried this `<Route path={path} element={React.createElement(component)}/>` and it makes the deal

Comment: It is not a component type, it is just a way to rename the `component` variable to capitalized form, as React expects components to have a capital first letter. Then you can use it as a normal component. (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter))

Answer (score 1):

You're using component as function but they are JSX.Elements.

Try to use as

```
<Route key={path} path={path} element={<component />}/>
```

And don't forget to place key.

Comment: This approach `<Route path={path} element={<component />}/>` causes error saying `Property 'component' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.`
I tried this `<Route path={path} element={React.createElement(component)}/>` and it makes the deal. Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem because if you don't use `<Routes>`.

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Routes>
                    <PageNav/>
                    <Route key={path} path={path} element={<component />}/>
                </Routes>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

You can view this [link](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/start/tutorial.md)

Comment: I'm using <Routes>. See my code snippets, in both cases Routes are wrapped by Routes element.

Comment: You're right, put it to me that I added a key

Comment: It still doesn't work ?

Comment: it works now, thanks. Passing `React.createElement(component)` makes the deal. But as Gabriele Petrioli mentioned, renaming `component` to 'Component` also makes it and seems to be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

as @dogukyilmaz mentioned, components are not functions. Passing component value to the Route component prop directly won't make the deal. On the other hand, passing `React.createElement(component)` makes it.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue is that you are directly invoking a React function component when the route is rendered ***and not*** when the route is matched and can correctly access props/contexts/etc as part of the React component lifecycle.

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map(({ path, component }) =>
    <Route path={path} element={component()} /> // <-- here
  )}
</Routes>
```

In other words, you are effectively rendering static JSX, i.e. the returned value of directly calling `component` as a function.

We do not directly call React functions in React, we instead pass them ***as*** ReactNodes, a.k.a. JSX.

## Solution

Given routes config:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Main,
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    component: About,
  },
  {
    path: '/posts',
    component: Posts,
  },
  {
    path: '/posts/:id',
    component: PostDetails,
  },
];
```

The mapped components should be passed as JSX, i.e. `<Component />`.

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map(({ path, component: Component }) =>
    <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
  )}
</Routes>
```

You may find it easier to align your routes config more along the lines for what `react-router-dom` uses. Replace "component" property with "element" property and update the `element` property value to be a `ReactNode` type.

Example:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Main />,
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    element: <About />,
  },
  {
    path: '/posts',
    element: <Posts />,
  },
  {
    path: '/posts/:id',
    element: <PostDetails />,
  },
];
```

...

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map(({ path, element }) =>
    <Route key={path} path={path} element={element} />
  )}
</Routes>

... or ...

<Routes>
  {routes.map((route) =>
    <Route key={route.path} {...route} />
  )}
</Routes>
```

Or because you've now effectively declared the routes config correctly as RRD consumes, pass it directly to the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) hook.

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from '../path/to/routes';

...

const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);

...

return (
  ...
  {appRoutes}
  ...
);
```